# NameError/undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to put my post model in another controller. Here are the concept and resources:

1. An Index controller, which contains methods like `home/about...` etc. to make the url look like `www.xxxx.com/index/home`.
2. A post model to make user about to post articles on it.
3. Devices gem.

When I run the following code,

- In `views/index/home.html.erb`:

  ```
  <%= render  "posts/post" %>
  ```
- In `views/posts/_post.html.erb`:

  ```
  <li id="post-<%= post.id %>">    
    <span class="user"><%= link_to post.user.name, post.user %></span>
    <span class="content"><%= post.content %></span>
  </li>
  ```
- In `models/post.rb`:

  ```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :content, presence: true
  end
  ```
- In `controllers/posts_controller.rb`:

  ```
  class PostsController < ApplicationController 
    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @posts = @user.posts 
    end
  end
  ```

it shows the error:

```
NameError` in `Index#home
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/posts/_post.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x007f105a04f7d8>:0x007f1058676d48>
Extracted source (around line #1):
1<li id="post-<%= post.id %>">
```

The `@post` or `@posts` do not seem to be the source of the issue because I have tried several times.

Comment: Post your full view template please as well as the User model. The partial and where you are calling it from. In your controller u appear to being using a collection of posts but from what I can tell you are accessing it singularly in your views.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how to make one controller (index) shows data from other controller/model (post) to make the index/home route able to show posts

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that there is no variable called `post` at that point in time. It is indeed possible to set variables in views but if you expect to get something from the controller here you are out of luck. In rails you typically set instance variables like `@post` or `@posts` to communicate with the view. To me it seems that you are missing a loop around your `render` call. Also - you are not passing in the actual `post` into the partial. In `home.html.erb` you probably want something like

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render post %>
<% end %>
```

to actually get any posts through to your partial.

Comment: Or depending on the Rails version, OP could make use of the partial naming convention he is following and just use `render post`